# Eclipse - pass and view raw HTML in SWT browser

Tags: eclipse, swt

Given a Browser object, it is possible to have it displaying content from a raw HTML string?

Of course, it is possible to save the string as a local file and then calling setURL() on the local path. But I am wondering if there's a solution without saving files on the local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `setText(String html)` method of `Browser` to give it HTML.